# Current monitor for a High frequency signal

Tags: operational-amplifier, rf

I'm working on a current monitoring circuit for a high frequency current monitoring application as shown in the schematic below, the requirements are as follows.

1. Should be able to provide RMS current feedback, the differential amplifier output would be fed into an ADC
2. the AC signal feeds into a resistor which connects to ground

will the LM7372 connected directly across the shunt work for this application? or is there filtering required before connecting to the LM7372 to get the RMS value?

[Update] Signal input is 13.56Mhz sine wave ±15V, Bandwidth is <1Khz, also added the LM7372 circuit below 
[image: Schematic]

please refer to the updated LM7372 Circuit 
[image]

Comment: There's a lot wrong here.  The LM7372 is an op-amp, you need feedback to make it useful.  It's not stable for a gain of +1, but you could potentially configure it as a differential amplifier with a gain of -1.  You show a diode in series with the output, which will reject any signal less than around 0.7V.  (Consider a precision rectifier.) You make mention of RMS current, are you planning to do the RMS calculation in software? Because the output of the current sense amplifier will not be RMS. You show a cap connected to the output, which will likely cause stability problems.

Comment: You might want to consider monitoring the current in one or both of the power connections to the upper amplifier, instead of putting your sensor directly in the signal path. This would at least make the sense signal unipolar, making it easier to do peak detection on it.

Comment: How accurate do you need to be, what's the expected current range, what's the expected *voltage* range, and what's the bandwidth of your "13.56MHz" signal?